# USB live key recognized by BIOS but not recognized on reboot?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, fedora

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu via live key. I successfully created the live key using Unebootin and I am attempting to format & fresh install on a computer currently dual booted with Fedora & Windows 8. 
It's using Gigabyte Dualbios and I can see the SanDisk USB show up on the BIOS settings console (both a legacy and a UEFI version). 
After saving the boot order & rebooting it shows me the same boot menu with the options to choose from Fedora & Windows 8. The Windows 8 installation is broken and the Fedora version is outdated (most programs work but the software center doesn't work). Safe mode is disabled and I can get the prompt for boot media when I set everything to UEFI only, but then the USB is not recognized.

Is there a setting I am not accounting for,some way to force the boot from the live key, or an alternative way to format & fresh install Ubuntu from within Fedora?

Comment: I'd recommend that you first fix the broken Windows 8, and then delete the old Fedora (if you don't use it any more), before trying to install Ubuntu. You'll save yourself a whole lot of grief later. To boot the USB key, hit F12 (or whatever it is on your computer) to bring up the interactive boot menu, where you can select to boot from the USB key.

Comment: I set all the settings to 'UEFI only' and now i see the message `Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media and press a key` however the USB isn't detected automatically and reinserting it doesn't do anything (pressing a key after re-inserting on this screen doesn't do anything)

Comment: Windows attempts to fix itself on boot attempt and fails and I have zero interest in installing Windows unless it's a last resort to installing another os. I've tried all settings set to legacy which defaults to the same windows/fedora boot screen and UEFI which gives me the insert Boot Media screen.

Comment: Can you boot another computer from the USB boot drive? Did you check the downloaded iso file with md5sum? Can you try to use another tool to make the USB boot drive bootable, for example Rufus or Win32DiskImager in Windows, or mkusb in linux? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb, https://rufus.akeo.ie/, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb

Comment: @sudodus Thank you for the suggestion, the livekey did not work on another computer. On a separate Windows machine I downloaded & used Rufus to create a new live key and it worked. I suspect that UNetbootin failed.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, and thanks for sharing it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following ways to find a solution:

- Try to boot another computer from the USB boot drive
- Check check the downloaded iso file with md5sum
- Try another tool to make the USB boot drive bootable, for example Rufus or Win32DiskImager in Windows, or mkusb in linux. See the following links,

  [rufus.akeo.ie](https://rufus.akeo.ie)

  [wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb)

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)